# Looking for socio research on "Latinx"

Tags: english, reference-request, spanish

I'll crib the intro from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latinx):

> Latinx is a gender-neutral English neologism, sometimes used to refer to people of Latin American cultural or ethnic identity in the United States.

"Latinx" is a somewhat controversial term, as WP continues:

> Surveys of Hispanic and Latino Americans have found that most prefer other terms such as Hispanic and Latina/Latino to describe themselves, and that only 2 to 3 percent use Latinx. A 2020 Pew Research Center survey found that roughly three-quarters of U.S. Latinos were not aware of the term Latinx; of those who were, 33% said it should be used to describe their racial or ethnic group, while 65% said it should not.

The citations in the article refer to popular press articles, based mostly on surveys and Pew research, which I don't generally have a problem with, but I'm looking for research by linguists on "Latinx" (and more broadly the related terms "Latine" and "Chicanx") among US residents and non-US residents.

Comment: The big problem with the term is how to pronounce it. When I see _Latinx_, I hear "Latinks", and it's hard to take that seriously, especially since it's not a Spanish word, or even Spanglish.

Comment: I find "Latin-x" pronounced like "Latin" pretty silly sounding, I think at least using "lateen-x" sounds a bit better (sorry too lazy for IPA)

Comment: Plus, the correct term in Spanish is Latine, because -e is a neutral ending (which is why words that end with e can be masculine or feminine).

Comment: @ILEMWorld Well, not sure I'd go so far as to call it "the correct term," but it is certainly a competing term, yes.

Comment: Well, it follows existing conventions in Spanish. It's like having an Italian word end in z or b. It just isn't natural.

Comment: @ILEMWorld Yes, I know.